No Twilio Console Errors, But Twilio Voice Call Does Not Go Through?
I'm working on getting Twilio app-to-phone voice calls working.
Here's my current flow.

Client clicks the "Make Call" button on my website.
My site sets up the Twilio device and calls const call = await twilioDevice.connect({ params });
On my server, the endpoint specified in Twilio App-> Voice Configuration ->Request URL is hit. This endpoint is called "/make-calls" (This all seems to work as expected up to this point).
My "make-calls" endpoint calls twilioClient.calls.create() and returns this xml to Twilio:

    <Response>
        <Connect/>
    </Response>


There are no errors shown in the Twilio Error logs, but in console.log on the client I see:


console.js:288 [TwilioVoice][Call] Received an error from the gateway:
ConnectionError: ConnectionError (31005): Error sent from gateway in
HANGUP
at Call._onHangup (call.js:291:23)
at PStream.emit (events.js:161:5)
at PStream._handleTransportMessage (pstream.js:148:10)
at WSTransport.emit (events.js:161:5)
at WSTransport._onSocketMessage (wstransport.js:156:18)

The client immediately hangs up the call. The callee's phone rings, but no one is on the other end to talk to.
My server console.log shows that '/twiml' endpoint is never hit, and neither is my 'handle-amd-result' endpoint.
What am I leaving out?
Here's the code from my "make-calls" endpoint:
    console.log('-----')
    console.log('/make-call. req?.body:', req?.body);

    let nurseId = req?.body?.nurseId;
    const navData = await getNavigatorData(nurseId);
    const toNumber = navData?.phone_1;
    let nurseName = navData?.name_first;
    const twilioPhoneNumber = Meteor.settings.private.twilio.phoneNumber;
    console.log('toNumber:', toNumber);


    let xml = '';
    const twilioClient = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
    try {
        const call = await twilioClient.calls.create({
            url: `${baseUrl}twiml`,
            to: toNumber,
            from: twilioPhoneNumber,
            // twiml: twimlString,
            machineDetection: 'Enable',
            AsyncAmdStatusCallback: `${baseUrl}handle-amd-result`,
            statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
            statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
            machineDetectionTimeout: 30
        })

        let responseObject = {
            Response: {
                Connect: true,
                Play: true
            }
        }
        xml = xmlJs.js2xml(responseObject, xmlJsOptions);
        xml = "<Response>\n" +
            "    <Connect/>\n" +
            "</Response>"
        console.log('xml: ', xml)
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        res.status(200).send(xml);
    } catch (err) {
        let responseObject = {
            Response: {
                Success: false,
                Message: 'Failed to initiate call',
                Error: err.message
            }
        }
        xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + xmlJs.js2xml(responseObject, xmlJsOptions);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        res.status(500).send(xml);
    }

